# Web Browser (Chromium/Firefox) becomes unresponsive for 1-2sec after file dialog

Tags: javascript, html

How can I improve this code in order to remove unresponsivness / page lag after selecing a file from file dialog and clicking OK?

I've been testing files with sizes around 50-100 KB

```js
function handleFileSelect(evt) {
  var files = evt.target.files; // FileList object

  // files is a FileList of File objects. List some properties.
  var output = [];
  for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {
    output.push('<li><strong>', escape(f.name), '</strong> (', f.type || 'n/a', ') - ',
      f.size, ' bytes, last modified: ',
      f.lastModifiedDate ? f.lastModifiedDate.toLocaleDateString() : 'n/a',
      '</li>');
  }
  document.getElementById('list').innerHTML = '<ul>' + output.join('') + '</ul>';
}

document.getElementById('files').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect, false);
```

```html
<input type="file" id="files" name="files[]" multiple />
<output id="list"></output>
```

I'm running this page on localhost and I'm using SSD

Thanks

Comment: Note: the `<input>` tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in HTML.

Comment: After you submit the form, the files have to be transmitted to the server, and the browser waits for a response (which may contain errors etc).

Comment: @Pointy I'm running this page on localhost, so 1-2sec still seems to be way too long for such a small file. Even files with 3 lines of text (let's say 30characters) aren't faster

Comment: @Rob ... except in xhtml (which, technically, isn't HTML, but it's close enough)

Comment: @SoftwareEngineer XHTML is not HTML. It's reformulated XML that *must* be served as `application/xml+xhtml`. It is not "close enough" if you are truly serving XHTML or using HTML.

Comment: How many files do you select in one go? What OS are you running this code from? When happens the lag, before the dialog appears? after? While processing the Files? The only thing that could take time is the IO from the disk, but you didn't even try to read it yet, just merely get the metadata...

Comment: @Kaiido Just one file. OS: Windows.. `When happens the lag, before the dialog appears?` after clicking `Open` in file dialog, so after it disappear

Comment: have you tried with other computer too ? this can come from your system performance

Comment: I just noticed that there's difference between file locations. e.g dialog is opened in folder with one file, then it runs instantly, but when I open it from `Desktop` with way more files, then it gets this lag

Comment: I copied your code, put it in a HTML file, and ran it from the desktop. Since this is pure javascript no "server" is needed. I can find no delay, no matter which files I select.

Comment: I would second BrightFaith's comment; this could have a lot to do with your system's performance. Recommend doing a cleanup/ deleting temp/cache files etc. and then retry, see if lag persists

Comment: I totally agree with what KIKO Software and BrightFaith mentioned. I just tried the code with files upto 1GB (in total), it loaded within 100ms!

Answer (score 4):

Your code is perfectly fine. Try [measuring](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/evaluate-performance/reference) the performance to investigate further:

---

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Use Promises in your **handleFileSelect** function or make **async** function of it.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works and there is nothing wrong with it.You can only improve performance by first measuring it and then taking appropriate actions.

For eg You may refactor the code to a cleaner approach -

```js
let handleFileSelect = (evt) => {
  let files = evt.target.files; // FileList object

  let output = [...files].map((file) => {
    return `<li>
                <strong>${escape(file.name)}</strong> 
                (${file.type || "n/a"}) - ${file.size} bytes,
                 last modified: ${
                   file.lastModifiedDate
                     ? file.lastModifiedDate.toLocaleDateString()
                     : "n/a"
                 }
                </li>`;
  });

  document.getElementById("list").innerHTML = `<ul>${output.join("")}</ul>`;
};

document
  .getElementById("files")
  .addEventListener("change", handleFileSelect, false);
```

```html
<input type="file" id="files" name="files[]" multiple />
<output id="list"></output>
```